# Issue with running bundle using Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, unicorn

I've seen this issue in a few other questions/Github issues, but they haven't been able to shed enough light to lead to the solution.

The error:

```
bash: bundle: command not found

SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as my-user@my-IP-address: cd /path-to-my-app/current ; bundle exec unicorn -D -c config/unicorn.rb -E production exit status: 127

cd /path-to-my-app/current ; bundle exec unicorn -D -c config/unicorn.rb -E production stdout: Nothing written
cd /path-to-my-app/current ; bundle exec unicorn -D -c config/unicorn.rb -E production stderr: bash: bundle: command not found
```

I'm using the latest version of Capistrano on my rails app. Specifically, it's a Rails 4.2.0 app with the gems `capistrano-rails` and `capistrano-rvm`.

I have a pretty standard `config/unicorn.rb` file, which is how I start unicorn while logged into my server. I first kill the current PID with:

```
kill -9 PID
```

Then I start unicorn with:

```
bundle exec unicorn -D -c /path-to-my/config/unicorn.rb -E production
```

This works great, but obviously I need capistrano to do that, so I essentially have those tasks in my `deploy.rb` file, however I get that error mentioned above. Here are the two tasks I have in `deploy.rb`:

```
namespace :deploy do
  namespace :unicorn do
    task :restart do
      on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
        execute "kill -s USR2 `cat /path-to-my/tmp/pids/app-name.pid`"
      end
    end

    desc 'Start unicorn' 
    task :start do
      on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
        execute "cd #{current_path} ; bundle exec unicorn -D -c config/unicorn.rb -E production"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have a similar task to restart DelayedJob, which throws the same error. The command is `execute "cd #{current_path} ; RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job -n2 restart"`. Like I mentioned above, when logged into the server with my user (same user I use for Capistrano), all of these tasks work as expected.

Every other *built-in* task works great with Capistrano, like precompiling assets, migrating my database, etc. It is the custom tasks I've added that are getting the error.

Let me know if I can add anything to help solve the problem.

Comment: Are you using rvm or rbenv on server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at output of Capistrano carefully. Such commands as `bundle assets:precompile` [makes initialization of required ruby version](https://github.com/capistrano/rvm#how-it-works):

```
cd /<app path>/20150301211440 && ( RAILS_ENV=staging /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm 2.1.5 do bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
```

Seems like you don't do it. So, probably you a using system ruby by default and it doesn't have a `bundler` gem.

Try to specify ruby version use RVM in your commands too. I think it should fix your problem.